# Can't compile Kotlin Jackson Extensions readValue(File)

Tags: kotlin, jackson

I am trying to use Kotlin Jackson extensions to do JSON conversions in my code. But for some reason, I am getting a syntax error when trying to use the `readValue(File)` function.

```
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.13.3'
---
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.jacksonObjectMapper
...
        private val objectMapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
...
            val factionList: List<Faction> = objectMapper.readValue<List<Faction>>(
                File(javaClass.classLoader.getResource("data/factions.json").file))
```

The error I get from the compiler is:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
readValue(JsonParser!, ResolvedType!)
...
[it lists all the valid function signatures ...]
```

However, none of the extension functions seem to be showing up in that list. If I click on the function and hit `Cmd-B` in IntelliJ, I am seeing the `readValue(File)` method in the extensions code.

I am confused why the function is not being found by the compiler.

Comment: DId you try manually importing the extension function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're most likely missing the following import:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.readValue
```

Forgot this a few times myself.